# How can I change a cell array consisting of int 32 and double to matrix of doubles?

Tags: matlab, double, cell, int32

I have a structure that I want to change it to a matrix. So I got `cell2mat(struct2cell(d))`. But `struct2cell(d)` gives me

```
6×1 cell array

{1100×1 int32 }
{1100×1 int32 }
{1100×1 int32 }
{1100×1 int32 }
{1100×1 double}
{1100×1 double}
```

and `cell2mat(struct2cell(d))` gives me the error:

> All contents of the input cell array must be of the same data type.

So my question is how can I convert all of them to double? Or how can I get a matrix finally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast each elements of your cell with `cellfun` (which is basically a hidden for loop):

```
%Dummy data
s.a = int16([1:4])
s.b = linspace(0,1,4)

%struct -> mat
res = struct2cell(s);
res = cellfun(@double,res,'UniformOutput',0) %cast data type to double
res = cell2mat(res)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`structfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) to loop over all fields in your structure and convert them to [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.html) first. Then you can use [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and [`struct2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct2cell.html) on the modified structure. Alternatively, you can get a cell array directly from `structfun` and simply concatenate those cell contents into an array:

```
>> s = struct('a', int32(1:10).', 'b', pi.*ones(10, 1));  % Sample data
>> mat = cell2mat(structfun(@(v) {double(v)}, s).');

mat =

   1.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
   2.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
   3.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
   4.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
   5.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
   6.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
   7.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
   8.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
   9.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
  10.000000000000000   3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 1):

We could just do a simple loop...

```
f = fieldnames( d );
nf = numel( f );
output = cell( nf, 1 );
for ii = 1:nf
    output{ii} = double( d.(f{ii}) );
end
output = [output{:}];
```

Comment: @gnovice overhauled my answer, you're right I hadn't realised that